# How to expose a NATS server externally

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nats.io

I have deployed NATS (https://nats.io/) into my Kubernetes cluster which is running on AWS and I am trying to expose this service externally.

These are the current details of my nats service.

```
NAME   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP  
nats  ClusterIP     None         None       

Port(s)

4222/TCP,6222/TCP,8222/TCP,7777/TCP,7422/TCP,7522/TCP
```

Currently, the nats service is a ClusterIP service and when I try to patch it to become a LoadBalancer service with this command:

```
kubectl patch svc nats -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'
```

It leads to this error:

> The Service "nats" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "None": may not be set to 'None' for LoadBalancer services.

Hence, how can I be actually expose this Nats service externally?
Any guidance provided will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When I started working with NATS I had a similar issue. For me, the best and easiest solution was to do port-forwarding:

```
kubectl port-forward service/nats 4222:4222
```

after doing this, you should be able to do:

```
nats server ping -s nats://localhost:4222
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably noticed that your `.spec.clusterIP` is set to `None`. Setting `None` will make the service `headless`. This is the exact reason why you are unable to patch this service.

Headless Service are used for service discovery mechanism and your `nats` service is used exactly for that purpose. Basically with headless service instead of returning single DNS A records, the DNS server will return multiple A records for your service each pointing to the IP of an individual pods that backs the service. So you do simle DNS A records lookup and get the IP of all of the pods that are part of the service.

In its essence `nats` service is used for `cluster-advertising`:

```yaml
          #this is snippet from your statefulset manifest (you can generate that using 'helm template'  
        - name: CLUSTER_ADVERTISE
          value: $(POD_NAME).RELEASE-NAME.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc
```

> If there exists a headless service in the same namespace as the pod
> and with the same name as the subdomain, the cluster's DNS Server also
> returns an A or AAAA record for the Pod's fully qualified hostname.
> For example, given a Pod with the hostname set to "busybox-1" and the
> subdomain set to "default-subdomain", and a headless Service named
> "default-subdomain" in the same namespace, the pod will see its own
> FQDN as
> "busybox-1.default-subdomain.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example".
> DNS serves an A or AAAA record at that name, pointing to the Pod's IP.
> Both pods "busybox1" and "busybox2" can have their distinct A or AAAA
> records.
>
> Taken from [services-networking/dns-pod-service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

Finally, instead of patching this service you should create a new service with type Loadbalancer.

---

For more reading please check:

- [Kubernetes/networking/headless-service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)
- [Kubernetes/expose-intro](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)
- [Kubernetes/expose-external-ip](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/)

Comment: I had a similar problem and attempted your solution but it did not work. Please provide an example of the commands to run here.